# Google Maps widget is not displaying in FlutterFlow app when I run the app. Grey screen issue despite working PlacePicker

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, content-security-policy, flutterflow

I have an issue with Google Maps. everything was working well until two days ago. Now, if I run the app I can use PlacePicker but GoogleMap widget doesn't come up, screen is grayed out.
I have different queries on maps so I created a separate page with a map without any query. Yet this map also is not working. As I said, PlacePicker works, so I believe there is no problem with the API.
After opening console i spotted an issue.
[image: [issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8879U.png)]
I am not sure if this is the reason of the behaviour, and also if it is I do not know hoow to fix CSP in flutterflow. I restored previous versions of my app to check the behaviour and it is the same.
All your thoughts and suggestions will be highly appreciated :) TIA
[image: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWyRx.png)]

- Checked API Key - Confirmed the API key is active and has the needed permissions. Still got a gray screen instead of the map.
- Made a Simple Map Page - Created a basic map page without extra features to test. The problem persisted with the same gray screen.
- Looked into Console Error - Noticed a CSP error in the console. Unsure how to fix this in FlutterFlow, and the map issue remains unresolved.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the issue so that the community could help you better.

Comment: It looks like that you are trying to render a webview of Google Maps within your app, which technically uses the Maps Javascript API. The CSP error itself shows what you ought to do. Though I'm not sure how to set up CSP in flutter flow, but there's an official documentation on how to configure CSP https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/content-security-policy